# Call between Javascript & Python with Flask: Method Not Allowed error 405

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm running a server with Flask. Here's my views.py:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/user_form.html', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template("user_form.html")
```

The user_form.html contains the following Javascript:

```
<SCRIPT>
    function get_UserInputValues(form) {
    var getzipcode = document.getElementById('user_zip').value;
    var getcuisine = document.getElementById('cuisine').value;
    var selection1 = $("#slider1").slider("value");
    var selection2 = $("#slider2").slider("value");
    var selection3 = $("#slider3").slider("value");
    var myurl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/mypython.py';

    /*alert(getzipcode);
    alert(getcuisine);
    alert(selection1);
    alert(selection2);
    alert(selection3);*/

    $('#myForm').submit();

    $.ajax({url: myurl, type: "POST", data: {zip: getzipcode, cuisine:getcuisine}, dataType: 'json', done: onComplete})

    }

    function onComplete(data) {
      alert(data);
    };
  </SCRIPT>
```

The user_form.html and mypython.py files are under the same "templates" directory. However, I get the message, " Method Not Allowed.The method is not allowed for the requested URL".

Looking at similar questions asked on Stackoverflow, I made sure to include "GET" and "POST" for methods. Why then I still have this error?

As a test, "mypython.py" is the following:

```
def restaurant_choice(zipcode, cuisine):
    print "zipcode:", zipcode
    return "cuisine: ", cuisine

restaurant_choice(getzipcode, getcuisine)
```

Comment: Check in the logs which verb is reaching the server. Is it really a POST? Sometimes clients send an OPTIONS and then GET/POST.

Comment: This is what I get as log in the terminal: 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jun/2014 19:20:41] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here:

1. You are not actually sending a `POST` request to `/mypython.py` - you are sending it to `/` (which is only accessible via `GET`, hence the error.)
2. You are both submitting the form (via `$('#myForm').submit()`) *and* making an ajax request via `$.ajax` on the next line - the browser will make the first for you and because that will result in a page navigation event it will *cancel* the second.
3. `/mypython.py` is not a defined route and so will result in a 404.  Flask only handles routes that are explicitly registered with it (`/static/<path:file_path>` is added for you automatically by Flask, which is why static files work).
4. Files in the `templates` folder are not exposed as served resources by default but are passed through Jinja (generally) by the `render_template` function.
5. In order to expose Python functionality to the end user (to use via JavaScript or as a web page) you should explicitly make it routable (either via `@app.route` or `app.add_url_route`).